# Why when i return the variable idx it's 0 all the time?

Tags: c#, winforms

In Form1 i have this code :

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                label1.Visible = true;
                label4.Visible = true;
                if (wireObject1 != null)
                    float t = wireObject1.GetIndexByXY(e.X, e.Y, 5);
```

Then in WireObject class i did i have this function :

```
public float GetIndexByXY( int x , int y , float tol)
        {
            for (idx = 0; idx < woc.Point_X.Count; idx++)//++idx)
            {
                float dx = woc.Point_X[idx] - x;
                float dy = woc.Point_Y[idx] - y;
                float dist = (float)Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

                if (dist < tol) return idx;
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

idx is float variables declared in the top of the class.
For the example in this case :

woc.Point_X.Count is 1 and indiex the List i see that index [0] is 435.0

x = 434 and y = 233
tol = 5.0

After the calculations : dx = 1.0
And dy = -2.0

In the end dist = 2.236068

and idx is 0

So maybe i shouldn't return idx ? And return maybe dist ?

I messed up with it i didn't touch this code for a long time. I dont remember whit it's returning idx and no dist maybe .

Comment: Because `(dist < tol)` is always `true` on the first iteration.

Comment: By the way, it's a terrible idea to use a field as your loop index like this. Use a local variable. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: How long did you spend with this code in the debugger? A breakpoint on the `return` and a few select watches would almost certainly have answered your question in very short order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why when i return the variable idx it's 0 all the time?

As you said the calculated value of `dist` on the first iteration is `2.236068` which is smaller than `tot` which equal to `5`. So because of:

```
if (dist < tol) return idx;
```

It returns the value of `idx` which is `0`.

> So maybe i shouldn't return idx ? And return maybe dist ?

It depends on what are you trying to achieve.